# JSON.parse parsing &quot; string

Tags: javascript, php, json, twig

I'm trying to pass a JSON string fron PHP controller to twig template this way:

```
$data['dist_result'] = json_encode($distribution_service->setDistribution($ids,$distribution));
$this->display('backend/shipments/distributor_selection.twig', $data);
```

and this is the javascript on the twig template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        var dist_result = "{{ dist_result }}";
        //var dist_result = dist_result.replace("&quot;","\"");
        console.log(dist_result);
        var data = JSON.parse(dist_result);
        console.log(data);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

It doesn't work with replace or without  it.

this is thee JSON string:

```
[
  [
    1,
    &quot;Mujer&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  [
    2,
    &quot;Hombre&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    0,
    0,
    2
  ],...
```

Comment: `var dist_result = {{ dist_result }};`

Comment: The twig xss injection filter, or similar, is likely at fault. You could tell it to not encode by using the `|raw` filter eg `{{ dist_result|raw }}`. Note you dont have to surround it in quotes and parse it. Just printing it straight out will make js see it as an object/array literal

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you want the server end to not html encode the result.

But if it's not possible to do this, then a simple approach is let the browser decode it.

eg..

```js
var txt = `[
  [
    1,
    &quot;Mujer&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  [
    2,
    &quot;Hombre&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    0,
    0,
    2
  ]
]`;

var b = document.createElement("div"); 
b.innerHTML = txt;
var j = JSON.parse(b.innerText);
console.log(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do instead of `dist_result.replace("&quot;","\"")` that will replace only the first occurrence `dist_result.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')`

Check more about [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Code:

```js
var dist_result = `[
  [
    1,
    &quot;Mujer&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  [
    2,
    &quot;Hombre&quot;,
    &quot;18-50&quot;,
    1,
    &quot;Zona1-Noreste&quot;,
    &quot;2&quot;,
    0,
    0,
    2
  ]
]`;
var dist_result_replaced = dist_result.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
var dist_result_parsed = JSON.parse(dist_result_replaced);

console.log(dist_result_parsed);
```

Comment: Note this could possibly mangle the json if some of the json content was legitimately encoded, eg if actual json was `{"prop":"some text with &quot;"}` you would change the content string `&quot;` to an actual quote which would lead to invalid json

Comment: @PatrickEvans  But would than actually happen, because `&quot;` would likely have got encoded to `{&quot;prop&quot;:&quot;some text with &amp;quot;&quot;}` .  But of course there is more things that can get HTML ecoded other than `&quot` anyway. Including the `&amp` as shown.

Comment: The best solutions is your answer @Keith +1

Comment: @keith true depends on what the twig filter actual decides to encode. It is just better to prevent the encoding in the first place instead of trying to reverse it